# How to center horizontally a segment from an ion-scroll element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Basically I have an ion-scroll with some buttons in it, that occupy more space than the window itself.
I would like that after you click on a button, to make it center horizontally on the screen.
With the following code, it works in Chrome, but not on mobile (IOS), and I can't figure out why.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; height: 32px; margin: 10px 0 20px 0;">
    <ion-segment nowrap [(ngModel)]="subject" *ngIf="rankingsSubjects.length > 1" class="various-width-segments">
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let subject of subjects; let i = index" [id]="'subject_'+subject.value" [value]="subject.value" (click)="centerButton($event)">
            {{subject.text}}
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-scroll>
```

And the .ts

```
centerButton(event) {
    event.target.scrollIntoView({inline: "center"});
}
```

I've also used this: (plus many other formats)

```
const el = document.getElementById(elementId);
el.scrollIntoView({inline: "center"});
```

Nothing seems to work on mobile, although in chrome it centers it perfectly.
I only tested on IOS, so I dont know if on Android it works.

Comment: please use https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: why? It works on the browser, but not on the app itself .. so showing it on this website, wont do any good

Answer (score 0):

COMPONENT.HTML

```
<ion-segment-button value="" (ionSelect)="segmentButtonClicked($event)">
  <ion-label>Heroes</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>

<ion-segment-button value="Marvel Comics" (ionSelect)="segmentButtonClicked($event)">
  <ion-label>Marvel Comics</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>

<ion-segment-button value="DC Comics" (ionSelect)="segmentButtonClicked($event)">
  <ion-label>DC Comics</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>

<ion-segment-button value="DC Comics 1" (ionSelect)="segmentButtonClicked($event)">
  <ion-label>DC Comics1</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>

<ion-segment-button value="DC Comics 1" (ionSelect)="segmentButtonClicked($event)">
  <ion-label>Marvel Comics1</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```html
  
segmentButtonClicked(event) {
    event.target.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth', //  smooth value triggers smooth scroll.
      inline: 'center'
    });
  }
```